# How to separate utm content from a link of varying length where the utm content falls in the middle SQL

Tags: sql, url

I'm trying to separate out a parameter in a link, namely utm_content= using SQL.

The utm content always falls directly after the end of the domain, after a ? and before an &. This is what I have come up with so far, but I'm getting an error.

I've created 3 columns for the data to be dropped into (as I have not succeeded in separating the utm content) called Domain, utmcontent and tracking.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

```
SELECT

CASE                   
WHEN Charindex(':',LastLinkClicked) > 0 THEN

Substring(LastLinkClicked,1,Charindex(':', LastLinkClicked)-1)


ELSE LastLinkClicked
          END AS Domain , 
          CASE 
                    WHEN Charindex('?',LastLinkClicked) > 0 THEN 
                              CASE 
                                        WHEN Charindex('?', Substring(LastLinkClicked,Charindex('?',LastLinkClicked)+1,Len(LastLinkClicked))) > 0 THEN Substring(Substring(LastLinkClicked,Charindex('?',LastLinkClicked)+1,Len(LastLinkClicked)),1, Charindex('?', Substring(LastLinkClicked,Charindex('?',LastLinkClicked)+1,Len(LastLinkClicked)))-1 )
                                        ELSE Substring(lastlinkclicked,Charindex('?',linkname)+1,Len(linkname))
                              END as utmcontent , 
                              CASE 
                                        WHEN charindex('&',LastLinkClicked) > 0 THEN 
                                                  CASE 
                                                            WHEN charindex('&', substring(LastLinkClicked,charindex('&',LastLinkClicked)+1,len(LastLinkClicked))) > 0 THEN substring(substring(LastLinkClicked,charindex('&',LastLinkClicked)+1,len(LastLinkClicked)),1, charindex('&', substring(LastLinkClicked,charindex('&',LastLinkClicked)+1,len(LastLinkClicked)))-1 )
                                                            ELSE substring(LastLinkClicked,charindex('&',LastLinkClicked)+1,len(LastLinkClicked)) 
                                                  END AS tracking
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider adding the error you are encountering to your question, to allow responders to help you better.

Comment: I'm getting "Errors: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'." - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your lowercase 'as' may be wrong. Try

```
SELECT

CASE                   
WHEN Charindex(':',LastLinkClicked) > 0 THEN

Substring(LastLinkClicked,1,Charindex(':', LastLinkClicked)-1)


ELSE LastLinkClicked
          END AS Domain , 
          CASE 
                    WHEN Charindex('?',LastLinkClicked) > 0 THEN 
                              CASE 
                                        WHEN Charindex('?', Substring(LastLinkClicked,Charindex('?',LastLinkClicked)+1,Len(LastLinkClicked))) > 0 THEN Substring(Substring(LastLinkClicked,Charindex('?',LastLinkClicked)+1,Len(LastLinkClicked)),1, Charindex('?', Substring(LastLinkClicked,Charindex('?',LastLinkClicked)+1,Len(LastLinkClicked)))-1 )
                                        ELSE Substring(lastlinkclicked,Charindex('?',linkname)+1,Len(linkname))
                              END AS utmcontent , 
                              CASE 
                                        WHEN charindex('&',LastLinkClicked) > 0 THEN 
                                                  CASE 
                                                            WHEN charindex('&', substring(LastLinkClicked,charindex('&',LastLinkClicked)+1,len(LastLinkClicked))) > 0 THEN substring(substring(LastLinkClicked,charindex('&',LastLinkClicked)+1,len(LastLinkClicked)),1, charindex('&', substring(LastLinkClicked,charindex('&',LastLinkClicked)+1,len(LastLinkClicked)))-1 )
                                                            ELSE substring(LastLinkClicked,charindex('&',LastLinkClicked)+1,len(LastLinkClicked)) 
                                                  END AS tracking
```

Comment: thanks for that - it now isn't erroring...but I have a bigger problem...The query is working but I can't get it to separate the utm content, as it is between two different symbols. The third parameter is separate, but with the utm content I just get a string "utm_content=Header_Logo&utm_source=sf&utm_medium=crm&..." is there something special i need to do to the query to get it to recognise that I want the information between the first ? and the first & ?? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure on that, but probably worth either editing your original question, or marking this one as solved and asking a new one with the new problem.

Comment: @kjohnson564 If the answer fixed your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation

Comment: apologies! Thanks for the advice